# What does the middle node of my Tor circuit know about my guard node?

Tags: bridge, guard-node, pluggable-transports, middle

Can the middle node of my Tor circuit detect if I am using a bridge and/or pluggable transport?

Answer (score 0):

With Nyx¹ (formerly tor-arm) you can see the IP, fingerprint and nickname of the Tor relays that form a cirquit. Middle node can see that a bridge is used, but not whether and which pluggable transport is used from the client (Tor-Browser) to the bridge.

¹Or other tools that use [Stem interpreter](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/down_the_rabbit_hole.html)

I don't want to show a productive relay. Hence: [Tor Nyx on a hidden service that syncs a blockchain.](http://www.boldsuck.mynetcologne.de/img/Tor-Nyx-Connections.png)

Answer (score 0):

No, it can't: because the middle node is contacted by the first node of the chain, you don't have any kind of direct connection to that node *and* the connection pipe is unified, i.e. if you're a node and you're contacted - you can not even determine what exactly contacts you - only the protocol commands matter